# Build upload from xcode 8 fails. No binary on itunesconnect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, xcode8

I was trying to upload a build(Version:2.1, Build:2.1.0) from Xcode 8. It failed with following error.

[image: Here's the screenshot]

After 9-10 failed attempts, I succeeded once but that binary is not appearing on iTunes Connect. It's been 15 hours since and the binary is still not appearing on iTunes Connect.

So I decided to perform following steps:

1. Re-archive and submit the build(Version:2.1, Build:2.1.0) again. It says the same build already exists.(I can't see it on itunesconnect)
2. Re-archive and submit the build(Version:2.1, Build:2.1.1). In first 6-7 attempts, it gave the same error as shown in the screenshot. But at last, the build was submitted successfully. (I still can't see any build on iTunes Connect)

Answer (score 0):

I contacted Apple support and here is the answer I got from them,

***This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data. 
Once these issues have been corrected, you can then redeliver the corrected binary.***

Applying this fix solved my problem. The binary get uploaded in the first attempt and it also has appeared in itunesConnect.

Answer (score 0):

Check your email, Apple will send you keys(from info.plist like NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription etc.) which you missed.
Just add all of them and fill up description in keys

Example :
    NSCameraUsageDescription
    Please allow the app to access your photo camera
    NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription
    App use Locations service
    NSMicrophoneUsageDescription
    Please allow the app to access your photo microphone
    NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription
    Please allow the app to access your photo gallery

Answer (score 0):

Try it using XCode 8... Open the Application Loader(Xcode -> Open Developer Tool -> Application Loader). Choose the build that you archived and then submit to the Apple Store.

Maybe, you need change the build version before do the step above.

It works for me. I hope that works for you!